# Unable to click HREF link

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies, href

I have a problem with href link. The bug just appeared after a while but worked well before. I hope you can help me.

Short description: A javascript countdown counting the seconds and stops at 0. There is another counting also which refest the countdown stopped value rarely (about minutes lenght). The website is static so no communication after load.

Problem description: While counting the seconds its not bugged but when it stops its no longer able to click just with "open link in new tab/window". The cursor status shows the unclickable link and a address appears in the corner.

The problem exists when I save the website.

Changes when the bug appeared: Added some new cookies. Included ob_end_flush().

JavaScript:

```
Gold.innerHTML = out;
```

JavaScript countdown ending:

```
if(!donea || ! doneb) window.setTimeout("timmer();", wait);
```

HTML/PHP:

```
echo '<a href="?view=gold" id="Gold">Gold</a><br/>';
```

Also use cookies, ob_start() and ob_end_flush() with PHP.

Comment: You talk about what you do in your PHP script but as we cannot see it we cannot know exactly what you have done. Also you dont show enough of your javascript. If you give us only bit of code and pseudo code at that, then all we can do is **guess**

Comment: its worked before. a site load well and the href link is working when counting. the javascript output is something like "30:12" or "24" as a string and the end value is "<b>[3]</b>" with any number in the middle

Comment: A validator found this (the > of </b>):
Line 60, Column 33: end tag for element "B" which is not open
 else out = '<b>[' + out + "]</b>";

Comment: My first thought is your js is crashing and leaving things in a bad state. But who can tell without more information. **No time to sit around guessing**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the output with any text and working well

```
out = 'Begyűjtés <b>[' + out + ']</b>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you quote html code in echo. Use "" quotes for the whole string in echo and use single '' quotes for the inner html attributes.

```
echo "<a href='link'></a>"
```

Comment: Sorry but that will make no difference at all

Comment: nothing changed. but thx for try to help me

Answer (score 0):

You must check what does JS do to your html, I think this is not a problem with server side but JS instead. As far as I understand after countdown is finished JS doing some stuff, maybe there is some html element witch z-index is set to larger number and it covers your link. I hope it helps but you maybe need to add some more explanations so we can help.